# Why Flash Firebug doesn't work with flex 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex

Why Flash Firebug doesn't work with flex 4.5?

UPDATE:

Hy!
I have Flex 4.5 and in the main application, in the script tag I write:

```
import ominds.Firebug;
```

I use flash player WIN 10,1,85,3 Debug enabled.
I export swf as 10.1.85 version.

And when I open the flashFirebug I get this:
"No SWF files with the O-Minds package found, you should import the O-Minds package into your flash files. For more information visit: o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug"

I appreciate any help (:

I'm using robotlegs if this matters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello man just get the new update "2.0" it works with flex and even you don't need to import the package anymore, and also you can debug any swf on the web :D

Answer (score 2):

Check out FlashFirebug 3.0, I haven't personally tried it with Flex, but it's reported to work. Here's the product homepage

http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your debugger to the latest version? As long as you're exporting to a SWF and to a valid version of Flash, it should work. I'm using the Beta Debugger for Flash 10.2 and I have no issues using Flashbug.

Comment: In my Application file I have this: "import ominds.Firebug;". Well, I'm running WIN 10,1,85,3 Debug enabled. In the FlashFireBug window I get this "No SWF files with the O-Minds package found, you should import the O-Minds package into your flash files. For more information visit: http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug"... Now I'm exporting for the 10.1.85 version

Comment: Are you using this extension? http://blog.coursevector.com/flashbug This is the one I use for all my Flash debugging.

Comment: Yes this one is working. But the flashFirebug (from http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug) is what I needed to make work with flex. Because let you go into the swf and edit and show properties live.